# How to use c# CompressSharper ZopfliDeflater

Tags: c#, compression, deflate

i'm trying to implement `zopfli` compression method into my simple `c# web server project`. I've read out `wiki` and checked out there is `c# source code` available for `zopfli` compression, but I've trouble in making the main program that using this `zopflideflater` to compress using `zopfli`, that the compressed file cant be read.

`ZopfliDeflater c# available here` :
[compressSharper](http://compresssharper.codeplex.com/)

Here is my code implementing `zopflideflater library`:

```
using System.IO;
using CompressSharper;

namespace Example
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string path = @"C:\webserver\first\index.html.gz";
            string inp  = @"C:\webserver\first\index.html";
            var filestream = File.Create(path);

            var zd = new ZopfliDeflater(filestream);
            zd.Deflate(File.ReadAllBytes(inp), false);


        }
    }
}
```

Any insight is much appreciated

Comment: Does your web app have the applicable permissions to write to that folder?

Comment: i havent write those code inside my web app anw, im still writing it on an example C# console application , it runs and returns a file, but it cant be read @AnthonyHorne

Comment: Do you mean that the compressed resultant file is not gz and cannot be uncompressed?

Comment: the resultant is gz, but cant open , and decompressed, maybe i miss some lines of codes to compressed it that causes the files is unreadable and cant be compressed @AnthonyHorne

Comment: Documentation says it is most useful for PNG optimisation, i.e. it works like IIS compression.  Try and compress a PNG and then try and open it in an image viewer (irfranview), i.e the compressed version.

Comment: i tried it just now and it cant be open, even using 7-zip @AnthonyHorne

Comment: No, what I am saying is use the CompressSharper on a PNG file and then attempt to open the "compressed PNG" with a image tool, i.e. something like irfanview (iview32).  Not opening in 7-zip.

Comment: ive tried it, it said 'unkown file format, empty/damaged file or file not found!' @AnthonyHorne

Answer (score 0):

You are not cleaning up any resources. Probably, data is lost on program exit in the `ZoepfliDeflater` buffers. `ZoepfliDeflater` has no way of making sure that it is finalized before the `FileStream` is (and I don't know whether it does any finalization work at all).

Clean up all resources.